# Можно получить Azure бесплатно имея подписку MSDN

Tags: node.js, azure

У меня есть подписка Enterprise MSDN, могу ли я получить бесплатно Azure для размещения свои node.js приложений?

Comment: Если у вас таковая есть, то почему бы не посмотреть свои привилегии на сайте Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Можете - как минимум по программе поддержки разработчиков `Visual Studio Dev Essentials`, список доступных возможностей вы можете посмотреть [на странице программы](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/dev-essentials/)